# Coding F1 formula with mathtools

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

I want to reproduce this formula. Note The `1` in the `F` should be subindex

[image]

This is my MWE which is not working for me:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
            \item \textbf{F1}. Conocido como el F-Score, se le denomina en estadística a la medida de precisión de un test. Resulta de la combinación de dos valores: precisión y exhaustividad. F=\frac{Precisión \times Exhaustividad}{Precisión + Exhaustividad}
        \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Additionaly, I don't know which format is better:

- `F` in italic or not
- `·` or `x` for multiplication
- the formula after the text or centering below it

Packages related with formulas in my .cls file are:

```
\RequirePackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to read a general introduction to LaTeX. For formulas you need math mode, you are not using math mode here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\frac` is only valid in math mode, so you want to either use inline math `$ ... $` or displayed math for your equation. You make a subscript in math mode with an underscore, i.e. `_{..}`. Also, you want to use `\text` for the words in your fraction.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Inline math: $F_{1}=\frac{\text{Precisión} \times \text{Exhaustividad}}{\text{Precisión} + \text{Exhaustividad}}$

Or displayed math:
\[
F_{1}=\frac{\text{Precisión} \times \text{Exhaustividad}}{\text{Precisión} + \text{Exhaustividad}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The 2 should be multiplied here.